# Count uppercase characters in a word

Tags: linux, string, shell, uppercase

I need to count how many uppercase letters there are in a word. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  When posting a question, please make sure you include the code of what you have tried, what research you have done, and a specific, minimum example that exhibits the incorrect behavior.  Then, we can take a look at it and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like tr for this:

```
echo "$word" | tr -dc A-Z | wc -c
```

simply delete all characters that are not uppercase and count what is left.

You might prefer `tr -dc [:upper:]`, but I find A-Z easier to use.

Comment: This elegant solution is, unfortunately, marred by only working correctly in English-language locales and mistakenly implying that `A-Z` and `[:upper:]` are equivalent; see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `grep -o '[A-Z]'` to match the upper case and then count how many times this occurred:

```
$ grep -o '[A-Z]' <<< "heLLo" | wc -l
2
```

Or even better ([thanks mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354249/count-uppercase-characters-in-a-word/30354293#comment48801026_30354293), always providing good info!), use `[[:upper:]]` so that uppercase will also consider the ones defined in your locale:

```
$ grep -o '[[:upper:]]' <<< "heLLo" | wc -l
2
```

Comment: Clever solution; I suggest using `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]`, however, so that the command works with accented uppercase characters as well.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

For **a solution that is *locale-aware***  and therefore **also works with *accented* characters**, use:

- EITHER: the `[[:upper:]]` variant of [fedorqui's helpful `grep`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30354293/45375).
- OR: the following *variant* of [William Pursell's elegant, but flawed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30354631/45375):

```sh
echo "heLLÖ, world" | tr -dC '[:upper:]' | wc -m  # -> 3
```

The changes are needed to correctly deal with non-ASCII, multi-byte-encoded characters.
Read on for a detailed explanation.

---

Keys to making the above command locale-aware:

- `tr`'s `-C` option uses the *character*-based complement, as opposed to `-c`, which uses the *byte*-based complement; while `-c` and `-C` may behave identically in some `tr` implementations, [POSIX defines only `-C` as the locale-aware variant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html).
- `[:upper:]` ensures that the *active locale's* definition of what constitutes an uppercase character is used, whereas `A-Z` only contains the *unaccented* (ASCII-only) letters from "A" to "Z".
- `wc`'s `-m` option counts *characters* (which may comprise *multiple* bytes in the now-prevalent UTF-8 encoding); by contrast, `-c` counts *bytes*, which, in the above example, would report *4* instead of the expected 3, because `Ö` is encoded as *2* bytes.

---

Now let's look at a statement from William's answer:

> You might prefer `tr -dc [:upper:]`, but I find `A-Z` easier to use.

- This mistakenly suggests that `[:upper:]` and `A-Z` can be used interchangeably and that choosing one over the other is merely a matter of preference or convenience - however, as discussed above, `[:upper:]` is locale-aware, whereas `A-Z` is not.
- Also, using `[:upper:]` *unquoted* makes it subject to pathname expansion (globbing), which means that if the current directory happens to contain files named either `:`, `u`, `p`, `e`, or `r`, `[:upper:]` will expand to their names, which is obviously undesired. The reason is that unquoted `[:upper:]` is treated by the shell as a *character class*.
- `wc -c`, which counts *bytes*, happens to work fine with `A-Z`, because all matching letters will by definition be *single-byte* characters; but switching to `[:upper:]` for locale-awareness necessitates switching to `wc -m`, so as to correctly count (potentially multi-byte) *characters*.